# Как присвоить переменной в python-скрипте значение из файла ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Ввожу команду `cat /etc/os-release` и получаю вывод:

```
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.4"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.4"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:4:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"
```

Так же есть файл **test.py**. Как можно переменной `"name"` в Python файле test.py присвоить значение переменной `NAME="Oracle Linux Server"`, полученное в результате вывода команды выше?
В результате хочу, чтобы переменной `name` присвоилось значение `"Oracle Linux Server"` примерно так:

```
>>> print(name)
>>> Oracle Linux Server
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
with open('/etc/os-release', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline().strip()

name = line.split('=')[1].replace('"', '')
print(name)
```